# How can we optimize the below PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell

My Intention is to update sql agent service password and out putting the same to html file.

```
$server = "LocalHost";$OldPass = "xyz";$NewPass = "abc"
[System.Reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement") | out-null
$wmi = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer") $server
$wmi.services | where {($_.ServiceAccount -eq '.\Ramu' -and $_.Type -eq 'SQLAgent')} | foreach {$_.ChangePassword($OldPass,$NewPass)}
$wmi.services | where {($_.ServiceAccount -eq '.\Ramu' -and $_.Type -eq 'SQLAgent')} | Select-object @{label="Server";expression={$wmi.name}},Name,Type,ServiceAccount,DisplayName,@{label="Status";expression={"Passwword update completed successfully on " + (get-date).ToString()}} | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>$server SQL Service Account Password Update Status</H2>" | Out-File D:\RP-TEST\Test.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered, probably because it is not clear what "optimize" means in your context. The only hint I can give you, is that:

- you can eliminate the `Where` part, because you call it twice
- long lines such as the last one are very hard to read. Cut them.

Edited code:

```
$server = "LocalHost";$OldPass = "xyz";$NewPass = "abc"

Add-type "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement" | out-null

$wmi = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer") $server
$wmi.services | 
    Where {($_.ServiceAccount -eq '.\Ramu' -and $_.Type -eq 'SQLAgent')} | 
    Foreach {$_.ChangePassword($OldPass,$NewPass); $_} |   # note the added $_
    Select-object @{label="Server";expression={$wmi.name}},Name,Type,ServiceAccount,DisplayName,@{label="Status";expression={"Passwword update completed successfully on " + (get-date).ToString()}} | 
    ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>$server SQL Service Account Password Update Status</H2>" | 
    Out-File D:\RP-TEST\Test.htm
```

Comment: I prepared the exact same answer. Didn't submit it. Seems pointless to "optimize" a script, if it is working and not running too slow.